# Display rows of same table in required format

Tags: mysql, join, group-by, sum, where-clause

From the below format

[image: pic1]

to this

[image: To this ;]

I could achieve till here ;

[image: I could achieve till here using "with" clause]

Kindly suggest ways if the required format can be achieved in two steps as well.

Comment: MySQL doesn't support a `WITH` clause, nor would that alone even help here in other databases.  You haven't done a good job of explaining your question.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen , apologies on that . but i could achieve till there .

Comment: I have no idea what you’re talking about. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are trying to group the a,b, a and b with sub totals. In the code below I have worked out which group each of the ids fall into and then created a union with some dummy values to acquire the sub totals.

```
/*
drop table if exists t;
create table t(id varchar(5), type varchar(1), value int);

insert into t values
('one','a',1),('one','b',1),
('ten','a',1),('ten','b',1),
('two','a',1),('three','a',1),
('four','b',1),('five','b',1),
('six','a',1),('seven','b',1);
*/
select 
        case when id like 'zzz%' then 'total' else id end as idout,
        case when type = 'xxx' then '' else type end as typeout,
        value 
from
(
select t.* ,
        case when t.type <> t1.type then 1 
              when t.type = 'a' then 2
            else 3
        end as st
from t
left join t t1 on t1.id = t.id and t1.type <> t.type
union all
(
select concat('zzz',st) id,'xxx' type, 
        sum(value), st
from
(
select t.* , t1.type t1type,
        case when t.type <> t1.type then 1 
              when t.type = 'a' then 2
            else 3
        end as st
from t
left join t t1 on t1.id = t.id and t1.type <> t.type
) s
group by concat('zzz',st) ,'xxx',st
)
) t
order by st,id
```

result

```
+-------+---------+-------+
| idout | typeout | value |
+-------+---------+-------+
| one   | b       |     1 |
| one   | a       |     1 |
| ten   | b       |     1 |
| ten   | a       |     1 |
| total |         |     4 |
| six   | a       |     1 |
| three | a       |     1 |
| two   | a       |     1 |
| total |         |     3 |
| five  | b       |     1 |
| four  | b       |     1 |
| seven | b       |     1 |
| total |         |     3 |
+-------+---------+-------+
13 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: @p-salmon , It worked .Appreciate your efforts to understand my question .